# How to run octave in emacs?

Tags: emacs, octave

I installed Octave from [Octave 3.8.0 installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20MacOSX%20Binary/2013-12-30%20binary%20installer%20of%20Octave%203.8.0%20for%20OSX%2010.9.1%20%28beta%29/GNU_Octave_3.8.0-6.dmg/download), which is Octave-forge. In terminal, I run Octave by `open -a Octave-cli`. Now I want to run Octave in emacs. I add the following line in the `.emacs` file :

```
(autoload 'run-octave "octave-inf" nil t)
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (abbrev-mode 1)
            (auto-fill-mode 1)
            (if (eq window-system 'x)
                (font-lock-mode 1))))
```

And when I enter `M-x run-octave`, it shows `searching for program: no such file or directory, octave`. [image]

Typing `which octave` in terminal only shows `octave not found`.

Comment: Have you read the "Appendix H Emacs Octave Support" https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Emacs-Octave-Support.html and please consider installing Octave 4.0.3: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Installing_a_Mac_OS_X_Bundle

Comment: Please remove your `autoload`s and your setting of `auto-mode-alist` since octave-mode comes bundled and preconfigured with Emacs.

Comment: In general, when Emacs complains it is searching for a program, there are two (2) likely suspects:  either the program has not been installed properly on the hard drive, or the $PATH within Emacs has not been configured to permit Emacs to locate the executable.  Rather than playing with the $PATH variable, I like to just use the absolute path to the executable by defining its location.  Usually, libraries written for Emacs have a variable for the program name.  For example, the grep library has a variable called `grep-program`.  These can be set with `(setq variable-name "/octave/program")`

Comment: Try:  `(setq inferior-octave-program "/absolute/path/to/octave/executable")` and, of course, use the right path to wherever it is on your hard drive.  This is the path to the executable itself, not just a path to the folder where it sits.

Comment: @lawlist, Thanks.  I found the right path and set it in .emacs. And it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Octave from Emacs on iMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247072/run-octave-from-emacs-on-imac)  [The solution there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250607/2708138) is almost exactly what lawlist recommended in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187956/how-to-run-octave-in-emacs#comment65772970_39187956).